# ¿Cómo obtener la ultima coordenada de una tabla con laravel excel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel, phpspreadsheet, maatwebsite

Muy buenas a todos...

Tengo el siguiente cod. que se encuentra en mi controlador de la clase, genera un archivo excel:

```
 public function export(Request $request)
{
    $institution = Auth::user()->institution_id; // Declara una variable cuyo valor es el "institution_id" del usuario con la sesión abierta

    if ($institution == 1 || $institution == null) {
        $practices = Practice::whereNotIn('state_id', [7])
        ->orderBy('state_id', 'ASC')
        ->get();

    }else{
        $practices = Practice::where('institution_id', $institution)
                ->whereNotIn('state_id', [7])
                ->orderBy('state_id', 'ASC')
                ->get();
    }

    if ($practices->isEmpty()){
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'No se pudo exportar la tabla de prácticas.',
            'alert-type' => 'error'
        );
        return redirect(route('practices.index'))->with($notification);

    }else{
        return (new PracticesExport($practices))->download('PRÁCTICAS ' . date('d-m-Y') . '.xlsx');
    }
}
```

La función anterior muestra las practicas de los alumnos dependiendo del rol que tenga el usuario logeado, todos los registros se exportan generando un archivo excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado no es el esperado, si bien le hice unos arreglos para que tenga bordes en los encabezados y el titulo, no puedo o no logro poner borde a todos los registros obtenidos, además, no funciona el ShouldAutoSize por alguna razón que desconozco...

La sgte. imagen muestra como espero que se vea la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo ideal es que las celdas de los registros obtenidos también pueda estar con bordes, el cod. donde diseño la hoja de excel es el siguiente:

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    // Borde grueso
    $borderMedium = [
        'borders' => [
            'outline' => [
                'borderStyle' => 'medium',
                'color' => ['argb' => '000000'],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    // Borde simple
    $borderThin = [
        'borders' => [
            'allBorders' => [
                'borderStyle' => 'thin',
                'color' => ['argb' => '000000'],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    // Fuente Negrita Tamaño 12 (titulos)
    $fontNegrita = [
        'font' => [
            'bold' => true,
            'size' => 12
        ]
    ];

    // Alinear al centro
    $colCenter = [
        'alignment' => [
            'horizontal' => 'center'
        ]
    ];

    $rowCenter = [
        'alignment' => [
            'vertical' => 'center'
        ]
    ];

    return [
        AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) use($borderMedium, $fontNegrita, $borderThin, $colCenter, $rowCenter)
        {
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setMergeCells( //Combina celdas
                ['A1:J1',
                'A2:J2',
                'A4:J4', // Fila intermedia
                ]);

            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->freezePane('A5'); //Congela las filas anteriores

            // Título
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:j1')->ApplyFromArray($borderMedium);
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A1')->ApplyFromArray($colCenter);
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:J3')->ApplyFromArray($rowCenter);
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:J3')->ApplyFromArray($fontNegrita);

            // Encabezado
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A2:J3')->ApplyFromArray($borderThin);

            // Tamaño de celda de las filas intermedias
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(25);
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getRowDimension('2')->setRowHeight(5);
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getRowDimension('4')->setRowHeight(1);
            // $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getRowDimension('6')->setRowHeight(5);


        }
    ];
}
```

**ACTUALIZO**: He respondido a mi propia pregunta y he editado el titulo de la pregunta para que sea más facil de encontrar, Agradezco que se hayan tomado el tiempo de leer y espero les sea de ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aquellos que necesiten encontrar la coordenada del ultimo registro obtenido, utilicé lo sgte:

```
$i = 5; //empieza a contar desde la fila 5 (ya que aquí empiezo a insertar datos)
            $lastCellAddress = null;
            foreach ($this->practices as $practice) { // Obtenido de la coleccion
                $lastCellAddress = $event->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10,$i)->getParent()->getCurrentCoordinate(); // Obtiene la coordenada de la columna 10 (es la ultima columna de mi tabla) y la ultima fila obtenida de practicas (al principio 5, mientras avanza el contador con el foreach, aumenta el numero de fila($i))
                $i++;
            }
```

Me apoyé con la siguiente pregunta: [How to get cell coordinates when iterating in PHPSpreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420538/how-to-get-cell-coordinates-when-iterating-in-phpspreadsheet)

Al obtener la coordenada del ultimo registro logré poner borde a toda la tabla exportada, por ejemplo:

```
public function registerEvents(): array{

$borderDashed = [
    'borders' => [
        'allBorders' => [
            'borderStyle' => 'dashed',
            'color' => ['argb' => '000000'],
        ],
    ],
];

return [

    AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) use($borderDashed){

        $i = 5; 
        $lastCellAddress = null;

        foreach ($this->practices as $practice) {
            $lastCellAddress = $event->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10,$i)->getParent()->getCurrentCoordinate(); 
            $i++;
        }

        $event->sheet->getStyle('A5:'.$lastCellAddress)->ApplyFromArray($borderDashed);
    }
];}
```

El resultado, sumando todo el código de la pregunta más esta respuesta, me entrega la siguiente tabla exportada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero les sea de utilidad, Gracias por leer!